# Why am I receiving only the first value for each element of the array?

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, mysqli

I am not able to figure out why all of my results are repetitions of the first values it returns.

This code returns the same ID and formatted date repeated over and over again; however, I was expecting it to read a value and then transform that value for each entry in the DB.  Here is my code:

```
<?php
include('../includes/conn.inc.php');
$stmt = $mysql->prepare("SELECT id, endDate FROM TABLE ORDER BY id");
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($id, $endDate);

while($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
    $dataRow[] = array('id'=>$id,'endDate'=> $endDate);
};

foreach($dataRow as $i) {
    $newEndDate = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($endDate));
    $sql = 'UPDATE TABLE SET startDate = ? WHERE id= ? ';
    $stmt = $mysql->stmt_init();
    if ($stmt->prepare($sql)) { 
        $stmt->bind_param('si',$newEndDate, $id);
        $OK = $stmt->execute();}
        if ($OK) {
            echo $id . " " . $newEndDate .  "done <br/>";
        } else {
            echo $stmt->error;
        } 
        $stmt->close();
    };
```

Comment: are you converting EndDate from the wrong format?

Comment: To debug that, ignore the `foreach` for now (which could be optimized but that's not related to your problem) and see if `$dataRow` gets constructed properly: What does `var_dump($dataRow)` output after the loop? What does it output inside the loop?

Comment: foreach($dataRow as $i){
print_r($i); echo "<br/>";  This outputted the array correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `foreach` you are always using the last values that were set from the **last** `$stmt->fetch()`

Try:

```
foreach($dataRow as $i) {
    $newEndDate = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($i['endDate']));
    $id = $i['id'];
    $sql = 'UPDATE TABLE SET startDate = ? WHERE id= ? ';
    $stmt = $mysql->stmt_init();
    if ($stmt->prepare($sql)) { 
        $stmt->bind_param('si',$newEndDate, $id);
        $OK = $stmt->execute();
    }
    if ($OK) {
        echo $id . " " . $newEndDate .  "done <br/>";
    } else {
        echo $stmt->error;
    } 
    $stmt->close();
};
```

Comment: This should not be an issue with `bind_result`. The references are updated with each `fetch()` call

Comment: When I output the array from inside the foreach like this, it works correctly. Its only when i run that second query that it returns a bunch of results with the same id and enddate
 foreach($dataRow as $i){

 print_r($i); echo "<br/>";

Comment: Add the results that you are getting back to the original post.

Answer (score 0):

use `get_result();`

```
$dataRow = array()
$stmt = $mysql->prepare("SELECT id, endDate FROM TABLE ORDER BY id");
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
while($row = $result->fetch_array()) {
    $dataRow[$row['id']] = $row['endDate'];
}
```

and you don't populate your $endDate in the second loop

```
foreach($dataRow as $i => $endDate){
    $newEndDate = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($endDate));
    ... // rest of your code
```